# TikZ connect two blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have a problem with the connection of two blocks. I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Block}[4]{
    \tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white!10, rectangle,minimum height=1cm, minimum width=1cm]
    \tikzstyle{container} = [draw, rectangle, dashed, inner sep=1em]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [block, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=0.5cm] (di)
            {#1};
        \node [block, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=0.5cm,below of  = di, node distance = 0.6cm] (BlockName)
            {#2};
        \node [block, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=0.5cm,below of  = BlockName, node distance = 0.6cm] (xi)
            {#3};
        \node[container, fit=(di)(BlockName)(xi)] (FTCBlockVal) (Blk)
            {};
        \node at (Blk.north west) [above right,node distance=0 and 0] 
            {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\Block{Val1}{Val2}{Val3}{Name}
\Block{Val1}{Val2}{Val3}{Name}


\end{document}
```

where I have now command to create a block. I will use many the same blocks.
The result is

[image]

So now I have a question. How connect this two blocks using an arrow?

Comment: from dashed line to dashed line?

Comment: Yes, or form a middle block to middle block.

Comment: Unrelated comments: I would define the styles outside the macro (seems pointless to define them every time the macro is used). And see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `blocks` are used inside a `tikzpicture` Andrew's `pic` solution is one option. I propose an alternative with a `matrix` node which simplifies the block definition. Being `container` style defined as a `matrix of nodes`

```
container/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    draw, dashed,
    inner sep=1em,
    nodes={block, anchor=center},
    row sep=.3cm,
    label={[anchor=south west]above left:#1},
```

the block command is just:

```
\newcommand{\Block}[5][]{
    \matrix[container=#5,#1] (#5) {
        #2\\#3\\#4\\}; 
}
```

The optional parameter can be used for blocks placement while the four mandatory parameters follow original `\Block` definition. In this case the fourth mandatory parameter acts as `matrix` name and label. With this matrix definition, inner nodes are identified as `matrixname-1-1|-2-1|-3-1`. An example of use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,matrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
    input/.style={coordinate},
    block/.style={
        draw, solid, fill=white!10, 
        minimum width=2cm, minimum height=.5cm,
        inner sep=.3333em},
    container/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        draw, dashed,
        inner sep=1em,
        nodes={block, anchor=center},
        row sep=.3cm,
        label={[anchor=south west]above left:#1},
    }
}

\newcommand{\Block}[5][]{
    \matrix[container=#5,#1] (#5) {
        #2\\#3\\#4\\}; 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Block{Val1}{Val2}{Val3}{NameA}
\Block[right=1cm of NameA] {Val1}{Val2}{Val3}{NameB}
\draw[->] (NameA)-- coordinate (aux) (NameB);
\draw[->] (NameA-1-1)--(NameA-1-1-|aux) |-(NameB-3-1);

\Block[below right=1cm and 2cm of NameB] {Val1}{Val2}{Val3}{NameC}
\draw (NameC-3-1)-|(NameB);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If `blocks` are drawn in its own `tikzpicture` and distributed over the page, `remember picture` option has to be used inside the `tikzpicture` parameters in order to allow to draw links (with another tikzpicture) between them

Answer (score 9):

I would define your block using `\tikzset{pics/block/.style=....}`. This way you can still use your `\Block` macro, so that

```
\Block{Val1}{Val2}{Val3}{Name}
\Block{Val1}{Val2}{Val3}{Name}
```

will produce the image in the original question. The advantage of a `pics` definition is that you can also put two blocks side-by-side in the same `tizkpicture` environment. Further, via a parameter given to the `pic you can label the nodes in each block differently, which means that you can easily refer to them in code like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0) pic{block={A,Val1,Val2,Val3,Name1}};% labels Adi, ABlockName...
  \draw(4,0) pic{block={B,Val1,Val2,Val3,Name1}};% labels Bdi, BBlockName...
  \draw[->,blue](Adi.east) -- (Bdi.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

will produce

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  block/.style = {draw, fill=white!10, rectangle, minimum height=5mm, minimum width=2cm},
  container/.style = {draw, rectangle, dashed, inner sep=1em},
  pics/block/.style args={#1,#2,#3,#4,#5}{% label, val1, val2, val3, name
    code = {
        \node[block] (#1di) {#2};
        \node[block, below of=#1di, node distance = 0.6cm] (#1BlockName) {#3};
        \node[block, below of=#1BlockName, node distance = 0.6cm] (#1xi) {#4};
        \node[container, fit=(#1di)(#1BlockName)(#1xi)] (FTCBlockVal) (#1Blk){};
        \node at (#1Blk.north west) [above right,node distance=0 and 0] {#5};
     }
  }
}
%\Block{label}{val1}{val2}{val3}{name}, label empty by default
\newcommand{\Block}[5][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0,0) pic{block={#1,#2,#3,#4,#5}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

  \Block{Val1}{Val2}{Val3}{Name}
  \Block{Val1}{Val2}{Val3}{Name}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(0,0) pic{block={A,Val1,Val2,Val3,Name1}};
    \draw(4,0) pic{block={B,Val1,Val2,Val3,Name1}};
    \draw[->,blue](Adi.east) -- (Bdi.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have put all of your style definitions together inside `\tikzset{...}`. I have also reduced the definition of `block` as you had different definitions for the minimum height and width in the style definitions and when they were actually used in the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use an application with a GUI, ie., Dia. The application can export to LATEX PGF macro's. "Dia is a GTK+ based diagram creation program for GNU/Linux, MacOS X, Unix, and Windows, and is released under the GPL license." (https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Dia?action=show&redirect=Dia).

You can easily include the diagram as follows in your document, for example:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1em}
\begin{figure}[bth]
    \centering
    \input{connect-two-blocks.pgf}
    \caption[Connect two blocks]{Connect two blocks.} 
    \label{fig:connecttwoblocks}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The pgf file below contains the connecttwoblocks figure drawn with Dia. Note that the size of the text "Valx" and "Name" can be adjusted with the scale property [framed,scale=0.7,every node/.style={scale=0.8}].

```
\ifx\du\undefined
  \newlength{\du}
\fi
\setlength{\du}{15\unitlength}
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed,scale=0.45,every node/.style={scale=0.8}]
\pgftransformxscale{1.000000}
\pgftransformyscale{-1.000000}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (7.350000\du,2.350000\du)--(7.350000\du,15.500000\du)--(18.350000\du,15.500000\du)--(18.350000\du,2.350000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{{1.000000\du}{1.000000\du}}{0\du}
\pgfsetdash{{1.000000\du}{1.000000\du}}{0\du}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (7.350000\du,2.350000\du)--(7.350000\du,15.500000\du)--(18.350000\du,15.500000\du)--(18.350000\du,2.350000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (12.850000\du,9.120000\du){};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (8.950000\du,4.300000\du)--(8.950000\du,6.550000\du)--(16.550000\du,6.550000\du)--(16.550000\du,4.300000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (8.950000\du,4.300000\du)--(8.950000\du,6.550000\du)--(16.550000\du,6.550000\du)--(16.550000\du,4.300000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (12.750000\du,5.620000\du){Val1};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (9.025000\du,7.350000\du)--(9.025000\du,9.750000\du)--(16.475000\du,9.750000\du)--(16.475000\du,7.350000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (9.025000\du,7.350000\du)--(9.025000\du,9.750000\du)--(16.475000\du,9.750000\du)--(16.475000\du,7.350000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (12.750000\du,8.745000\du){Val2};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (9.025000\du,10.550000\du)--(9.025000\du,13.100000\du)--(16.475000\du,13.100000\du)--(16.475000\du,10.550000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (9.025000\du,10.550000\du)--(9.025000\du,13.100000\du)--(16.475000\du,13.100000\du)--(16.475000\du,10.550000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (12.750000\du,12.020000\du){Val3};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (7.700000\du,1.600000\du){Name1};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (23.905000\du,2.275000\du)--(23.905000\du,15.425000\du)--(34.905000\du,15.425000\du)--(34.905000\du,2.275000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{{1.000000\du}{1.000000\du}}{0\du}
\pgfsetdash{{1.000000\du}{1.000000\du}}{0\du}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (23.905000\du,2.275000\du)--(23.905000\du,15.425000\du)--(34.905000\du,15.425000\du)--(34.905000\du,2.275000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (29.405000\du,9.045000\du){};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (25.505000\du,4.225000\du)--(25.505000\du,6.475000\du)--(33.105000\du,6.475000\du)--(33.105000\du,4.225000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (25.505000\du,4.225000\du)--(25.505000\du,6.475000\du)--(33.105000\du,6.475000\du)--(33.105000\du,4.225000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (29.305000\du,5.545000\du){Val1};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (25.580000\du,7.275000\du)--(25.580000\du,9.675000\du)--(33.030000\du,9.675000\du)--(33.030000\du,7.275000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (25.580000\du,7.275000\du)--(25.580000\du,9.675000\du)--(33.030000\du,9.675000\du)--(33.030000\du,7.275000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (29.305000\du,8.670000\du){Val2};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (25.580000\du,10.475000\du)--(25.580000\du,13.025000\du)--(33.030000\du,13.025000\du)--(33.030000\du,10.475000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (25.580000\du,10.475000\du)--(25.580000\du,13.025000\du)--(33.030000\du,13.025000\du)--(33.030000\du,10.475000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (29.305000\du,11.945000\du){Val3};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (24.650000\du,1.700000\du){Name2};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (16.599699\du,5.402364\du)--(25.505000\du,5.350000\du);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```